# Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 won't boot after fresh install

Tags: boot, server, grub2, system-installation

I've repeatedly tried doing a brand new install of Ubuntu Server to an ancient computer (Intel ECG3510M) w/ a dedicated Samsung SSD (in other words, no Windows OS).  Goes through the entire install, but after reboot "no boot drive found"

The ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso doesn't seem to have a "try" option -- instead it always goes straight to installing the OS, so I don't have a method to go out to a shell and examine grub's status.

How do I fix things so the machine actually boots? boot-repair-disk-32bit.iso just hangs -- two dots have changed color after like three hours.

The machine had been running Ubuntu 4.4.0-78, but the /boot somehow got erased and I'm trying to recover from that.  All I really care about is restoring the ZFS pool that existed under the old configuration.

Comment: Ubuntu Server does not have a “Try” mode but, if your server has some basic video capabilities, you may be able to boot a desktop image and use the “Try” option there. If your video subsystem has less than 64MB of memory, the Xubuntu Desktop flavour may be the way to go, as that desktop requires less video memory to function.

Comment: Ubuntu Server still allows you to open a shell: Navigate to "Help" at the top right, then "Enter shell".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the boot priority changed somehow to always boot from disk or boot from the wrong drive? Go into the boot menu when your computer restarts. You can do this py pressing either Esc, F2, F10, or F12 which are some of the common device specific keys, but it could change in your case. Then look for an option to switch from which drive the computer boots from. There you will get an idea if this is the issue. Hope this helps